# Adding a google map image on page without touching the <head> section

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I´m trying to put a google maps image into my HTML page. I cannot touch the `<head>` section as the page is dynamically loaded using PHP code (this logic is not explained here).

So, I´ve build the following HTML test code, that doesn´t work - the maps does not appear on screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>TEST PAGE</title>
   </head>

   <body>

        <h1>Maps test page.</h1>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            function initialize() {

                alert("Initialize");

                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("mapCanvas");

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                alert("Onload");
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js";
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }

            </script>

            <div id="mapCanvas" style="width: 650px; height: 350px;"></div>";
            <script type="text/javascript"> initialize() </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

The alerts are coming up, but no map is shown...

Help is appreciated to make is work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Asynchronously load the Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API), use the `callback` parameter to run your `initialize` function.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_asyncLoad_noHeadA.html)

```
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>TEST PAGE</title>
   </head>

   <body>

        <h1>Maps test page.</h1>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            function initialize() {

                alert("Initialize");

                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("mapCanvas");

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                alert("Onload");
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize";
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }

            </script>

            <div id="mapCanvas" style="width: 650px; height: 350px;"></div>";


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `initialize()` is getting executed before the Google Maps Javascript has been added to the page. You aren't importing the Google Maps JS until the DOM has finished loading, in your `window.onload` callback. Try this instead:

```
<div id="mapCanvas" style="width: 650px; height: 350px;"></div>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    alert("Initialize");
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("mapCanvas");
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    initialize();
  };
</script>
```